# Sql joins - do they have to be chained together in any particular way?

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query with about 10 joins. One of the joins is causing me some confusion. My joins are laid out like so:

```
SELECT TableA.colum1, TableJ.column1
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.someColumn = TableB.someColumn
INNER JOIN TableC ON TableC.someColumn = TableB.someColumn
```

So, they are chained together in a way. Then I have this join, where TableA is reused, joining on a different column than from beore. It could be that I'm just not used to this happening in queries, so my understanding isn't clear.

```
INNER JOIN TableJ ON TableA.someOtherColumn = TableJ.someColumn
```

Does this seem strange to anyone else? You can join two new tables in a series of joins?

Thanks.

Comment: Learn about foreign keys,you JOIN based on the columns different tables are linked to So tableA might be linked to table B on x column and with tableC on y column

Comment: I understand foreign keys. I'm just not used to seeing joins between tables completely unrelated to the previous joins.

Comment: May I ask what are you trying to achieve? I didn't quite understand your question.

Comment: What's not clear ? I didn't understand where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to be clear, you have something like:

```
SELECT TableA.colum1, TableJ.column1
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.someColumn = TableB.someColumn
INNER JOIN TableC ON TableC.someColumn = TableB.someColumn
INNER JOIN TableJ ON TableA.someOtherColumn = TableJ.someColumn
```

and you are wondering if that is valid?

The answer is "it depends but probably yes."  Assuming your join conditions are correct, yes, this is fine. SQL is relational. It is absolutely valid to join table A to table B using column 1 and table A to table J using column 2 (or 3 or 27 or whatever).

You might want to investigate your indices and make sure your joins are optimal...but certainly there is nothing illegal about what you are doing. There is no notion of tables needing to be chained together, for instance, or that only one column can be used. The only concern I would have is performance, and making sure you have the correct indices to support your joins. Here, run EXPLAIN in front of your SQL statement and investigate the output. http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/ may come in handy.

Answer (score 3):

This is not strange at all: `TableA` can have multiple *foreign keys* "connected" to different tables, letting you join to multiple tables as needed.

In this situation, both foreign keys are required, so you do your inner joins. In other situations the keys may be optional, in which case you would use outer joins. What's important, though, is that a table can have as many foreign keys as your model sees necessary, so having several joins originating from the same table is completely natural.